# Cannot understand timeit output

Tags: python, timeit

my problem is this:

```
>>> 999 in list(xrange(1000))
True # this takes a glimpse
```

Instead:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('999 in list(xrange(1000))')
26.88947892189026
```

Why does `timeit` gives such a high output?

Thank you

Comment: Look at the `timeit` call signature: `timeit.timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<default timer>, number=1000000)`. By default it runs 1000000 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it does this *1 million times* !
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit

---

`timeit.timeit` takes a positional argument `number` which defaults to `1.000.000` so it indeed takes longer to do the statement 1 million times compared to only one.

If you do this 1 time, it's way faster :

```
In [2]: timeit.timeit('999 in list(xrange(1000))')
Out[2]: 31.733104944229126

In [3]: timeit.timeit('999 in list(xrange(1000))', number=1)
Out[3]: 4.5061111450195312e-05
```

Comment: Anyways, I find it weird to give such a default option and not to return an average of elapsed times.  
When somebody does `timeit.timeit('foo()')` he is interested in knowing how long would it take to execute `foo` and not how long would it take to execute `foo` a million times, I think.  
It is an opinion, though.

Comment: Yes, that's an opinion. I share it though and also went wtf the first time I used it without reading the docs. But that's how it works ! Please check one answer if your problem is solved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
timeit.timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<default timer>, number=1000000)
```

Stupid question, the default number of times the statement is executed is one million... I should have read `timeit` doc before...

```
>>> timeit.timeit('999 in list(xrange(1000))', number=1)
9.083747863769531e-05
```

Comment: `number=1` produces unreliable timings. You could use command-line interface: `python -mtimeit '999 in xrange(1000)'` or divide the result by number of repeatitions and take a minimum from several measurements (`repeat()` function).